# Make force export of SSRS report in Word format

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am trying to make SSRS force export report in Word format but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want report to be displayed in browser from where you can select export option. Instead I want report to be directly exported to Word.

I found about about Device Information Settings through which you can pass different parameters to your report to render it differently. I tried the following URL to force export in Word but it always displays in browser. Has anyone done this before?

```
http://myserver/ReportServer?%2fExport%2fStudent_Report&rc:Toolbar=False&rc:OutputFormat=Word&rc:Format=Word&rc:Command=Render&STUDENT_ID=5
```

More about Device Information Settings here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `http://myserver/ReportServer?%2fExport%2fStudent_Report&rs:Format=Word&rs:Command=Render&STUDENT_ID=5`

The format syntax is rs: not rc: check out the full url reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: btw - I just discovered that there seems to be an undocumented type which is WORDOPENXML - this will output docx files instead of WORD which outputs doc files